# Ruby Sinatra JSON settings

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra, settings

I wrote this extension in Sinatra:

```
#extension.rb
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'json'

    module Sinatra
      module Ibaf
        module Helpers

          def test
            payload = settings.my_json.dup
            payload["test"] << "DONE"
            puts payload
            "OK"
          end   

        end

        def self.registered(app)
          app.helpers Ibaf::Helpers
          app.set :my_json, JSON.parse('{"test":[]}')

          app.get "/" do
             test
          end
        end

      end   
      register Ibaf
    end
```

and myapp.rb

```
#app.rb
require 'sinatra'
require './extension.rb'
```

and running as jruby -S app.rb -p 80

On first call to http://localhost the `payload` variable contains one element `"DONE"`. 
On the second call `payload` contains two elements, why?
I expect that `settings.my_json.dup` return new object, why is modified?

This is the output:

```
== Sinatra (v2.0.0) has taken the stage on 80 for development with backup from T
rinidad
Deploying from C:/Users/adminlocale/Desktop as /
Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.0.0.1-80"]
Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.0.0.1-80"]
{"test"=>["DONE"]}
127.0.0.1 -  [16/Oct/2018:17:08:42 +0200] "GET / " 200 2 0.1110

{"test"=>["DONE", "DONE"]}
127.0.0.1 -  [16/Oct/2018:17:08:51 +0200] "GET / " 200 2 0.0250
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shallow copying the hash. Which means that your `payload` has a new `object_id`, but `payload["test"]` still points to the same object.

```
[2] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> settings.my_json["test"].object_id
=> 47444101678660
[3] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> settings.my_json.dup["test"].object_id
=> 47444101678660
```

If you want to deep clone (there are several ways to do that):

```
[5] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> payload = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(settings.my_json))
=> {"test"=>[]}
[6] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> payload["test"].object_id
=> 70216811281680
```